# How do I add a view separator between rows in a LazyHGrid?

Tags: swiftui

I want to add a divider line between each row of the grid. Currently we are adding a bottom line to each view in the grid to achieve this, but when the user scrolls horizontally right and reaches the top, the line does not extend since it is in the grid view. Is it possible to add a separate view/line between grid rows in SwiftUI?

```
LazyHGrid(rows: positionsGridViewModel.gridRows, spacing: 0) {
      ForEach(positionsGridViewModel.positionValueViewModels) { positionValueViewModel in
             PositionValueView(positionValueViewModel: positionValueViewModel)
                   .frame(width: Constants.gridColumnWidth)
                   .accessibility(label: Text(positionValueViewModel.accessibilityLabel))}
```

Comment: you could try: "VStack { PositionValueView(...); Divider() }"

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Are you unable to comprehend the question? Did anyone ask for Stack?

Answer (score 0):

not so elaborated, but works.
Inside your "productCell" (You will fill a lot in forEach...)

...

```
            } // HStack for text of product...

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1)
                .foregroundColor( Color( UITableView().separatorColor ?? .gray) )
                .frame(height: 4)

            Spacer(minLength: 6)
            
            
        }// VStack
} // end of body of cell.
```

doing so I got:

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Or simply, doing a small View:

```
            } // HStack
            CellSeparator(spaceAfter: 6)
     }// VStack
} // end of body of cell.
```

our "CellSeparator" view:

```
struct CellSeparator: View {
    var spaceAfter: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1)
            .foregroundColor( Color( UITableView().separatorColor ?? .gray) )
            .frame(height: 4)
            Spacer(minLength: spaceAfter)

        }
    }
}
```